# android websocket client timeout

Tags: android, client-server, websocket, tornado

Thanks for reading!

**Background:**
I am developing an Android client for a server where the requirement is  app that requires continuous exchange of messages back and forth with a  `WebSockets`-based server.

**Implementation:** For the client, I use [weberknecht's](http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht/) `WebSocket` client library for Android while the server is `Tornado`-based.

**Problem:**
For the moment, I invoke `initWebSocketClient` in `onCreate` by spawning an `AsyncTask`. But, I keep getting a client timeout exception.

**Android Client:**

```
private void initWebSocketClient() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initWebSocketClient");
        try {
            URI url = new URI("ws://192.168.207.84:8080/");
            WebSocket websocket = new WebSocketConnection(url);

            // Register Event Handlers
            websocket.setEventHandler(new WebSocketEventHandler() {
                    public void onOpen()
                    {
                            Log.e(TAG, "--open");
                    }

                    public void onMessage(WebSocketMessage message)
                    {
                            Log.e(TAG, "--received message: " + message.getText());
                    }

                    public void onClose()
                    {
                            Log.e(TAG, "--close"); 
                    }
            });

            // Establish WebSocket Connection
            websocket.connect();

            // Send UTF-8 Text
            websocket.send("hello world");

            // Close WebSocket Connection
            websocket.close();
        }
        catch (WebSocketException wse) {
                wse.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException use) {
                use.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Tornado Server:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket

class EchoWebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print "WebSocket opened"

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.write_message(u"You said: " + message)

    def on_close(self):
        print "WebSocket closed"

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", EchoWebSocketHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8080)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

**Client Timeout exception:**

```
01-31 19:28:01.367: W/System.err(5668): de.roderick.weberknecht.WebSocketException: error while creating socket to ws://192.168.207.84:8080/
01-31 19:28:01.386: W/System.err(5668):     at de.roderick.weberknecht.WebSocketConnection.createSocket(WebSocketConnection.java:244)
01-31 19:28:01.386: W/System.err(5668):     at de.roderick.weberknecht.WebSocketConnection.connect(WebSocketConnection.java:83)
01-31 19:28:01.386: W/System.err(5668):     at com.sagar.websockclient.MainActivity.initWebSocketClient(MainActivity.java:55)
01-31 19:28:01.390: W/System.err(5668):     at com.sagar.websockclient.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:30)
01-31 19:28:01.390: W/System.err(5668):     at com.sagar.websockclient.MainActivity$WebSocketTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:75)
01-31 19:28:01.390: W/System.err(5668):     at com.sagar.websockclient.MainActivity$WebSocketTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
01-31 19:28:01.390: W/System.err(5668):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
01-31 19:28:01.390: W/System.err(5668):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-31 19:28:01.390: W/System.err(5668):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-31 19:28:01.390: W/System.err(5668):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-31 19:28:01.390: W/System.err(5668):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-31 19:28:01.390: W/System.err(5668):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-31 19:28:01.390: W/System.err(5668): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.207.84 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
01-31 19:28:01.390: W/System.err(5668):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
01-31 19:28:01.394: W/System.err(5668):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-31 19:28:01.394: W/System.err(5668):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
01-31 19:28:01.394: W/System.err(5668):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
01-31 19:28:01.394: W/System.err(5668):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
01-31 19:28:01.394: W/System.err(5668):     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:177)
01-31 19:28:01.394: W/System.err(5668):     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:149)
01-31 19:28:01.394: W/System.err(5668):     at de.roderick.weberknecht.WebSocketConnection.createSocket(WebSocketConnection.java:238)
01-31 19:28:01.394: W/System.err(5668):     ... 11 more
01-31 19:28:01.394: W/System.err(5668): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
01-31 19:28:01.398: W/System.err(5668):     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
01-31 19:28:01.398: W/System.err(5668):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
01-31 19:28:01.398: W/System.err(5668):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
01-31 19:28:01.398: W/System.err(5668):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-31 19:28:01.398: W/System.err(5668):     ... 18 more
```

Could someone please help me out here?

**Update:** Adding AutoBahn (WebSocket client library for Android) implementation details:

**AutoBahn Client**

```
private void connect2() {
        mConnection = new WebSocketConnection();
        final String wsuri = "ws://192.168.0.137:8888/";
        String TAG = "ArticlesListActivity"; 

        try {
            mConnection.connect(wsuri, new WebSocketHandler() {
               @Override
               public void onOpen() {
                 Log.e(TAG, "Connected to: " + wsuri);
               }

               @Override
               public void onTextMessage(String payload) {
                  Log.e(TAG, "Message recieved = " + payload);
               }

               @Override
               public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
                  Log.e(TAG, "Connection Lost.");
               }
            });
         } catch (WebSocketException e) {

            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
         }      
    }
```

With this library - I am able to connect to the server but instantly, the connection is lost. (Refer the "AutoBahn Client Log" below. Switching back to weberknecht works just fine. I am NOT explicitly calling `mConnection.disconnect()` anywhere. So I don't know how the connection gets terminated.

**AutoBahn Client Log**

```
02-27 14:27:36.605: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(27701): created
02-27 14:27:36.656: D/dalvikvm(27701): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 164K, 4% free 9247K/9543K, paused 17ms
02-27 14:27:36.671: D/dalvikvm(27701): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7K, 4% free 9368K/9735K, paused 14ms
02-27 14:27:36.671: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(27701): created
02-27 14:27:36.675: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(27701): WS reader created and started
02-27 14:27:36.675: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(27701): running
02-27 14:27:36.675: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter(27701): created
02-27 14:27:36.675: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(27701): WS writer created and started
02-27 14:27:36.769: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(27701): run() : ConnectionLost
02-27 14:27:36.773: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(27701): ended
02-27 14:27:36.777: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(27701): opening handshake received
02-27 14:27:36.777: E/ArticlesListActivity(27701): Connected to: ws://192.168.0.137:8888/
02-27 14:27:36.781: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(27701): fail connection [code = 3, reason = WebSockets connection lost
02-27 14:27:36.784: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(27701): quit
02-27 14:27:36.788: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter(27701): ended
02-27 14:27:36.792: E/ArticlesListActivity(27701): Connection Lost.
02-27 14:27:36.792: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(27701): worker threads stopped
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would start troubleshooting this:

1. Are you attempting to do this on your phone (device) or the emulator? If you're attempting to do this on your phone *and* you're connected via 3G, it is not going to happen. In this scenario, you're attempting to connect to an *internal* IP address from the WAN which doesn't work.
2. Again assuming you're doing this on a device, if you're connected via Wifi then it's another story. Make sure the server can be *reached* at `192.168.207.84:8080`. A quick way to test connectivity (from your PC):

   ```
   telnet 192.168.207.84 8080
   ```

   If it times out, you know your server isn't responding. This of course assumes your PC is on the *same subnet* as your Wifi network.
3. If you're attempting to do this from your emulator, follow the steps in [2] to make sure the server is reachable and also ensure your emulator is in (IP) bridged mode.

To summarize, the *main* reason timeouts usually occur is because of lack of server availability (i.e. lack of connectivity). You didn't mention the details of your network so I made a few assumptions here based on the IP you were trying to connect to (192.168.207.84).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @Marvin for the detailed explanation, that totally helped me solve the problem. I was using a device but my server was on an internal IP. So, now I logged both the server and the device on the same wifi and was able to get it to connect the server!

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see, Weberknecht does only support Hybi-10, not the final RFC6455 spec, and more problematic, does it's networking on the main (UI) thread. That is generally a bad idea, and will fail on Android >2.

For Android native apps, there is Autobahn WebSockets for Android

https://github.com/oberstet/AutobahnAndroid

It supports the final RFC6455, integrates well with UI and service apps, provides RPC and PubSub over WebSockets, and more. Check out the project README on GitHub.

Disclaimer: I am the author of Autobahn.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Your solution sounds full-fledged and I had looked at back when I was researching but I didn't see a WebSockets for Android here: http://www.tavendo.de/autobahn/tutorials.html BTW, just wondering if it's free for commercial use?

Comment: BTW, I spawn an AsyncTask for the websockets network activity so, it works fine for now.

Comment: Code is under Apache 2.0 license .. open-source. Rgd. AsyncTask .. with the latest code you dont need that, since not only the socket read/write are done on background threads, but also the initial socket connect. That latter point was different until just recently .. did read/write on background thread, but not the initial socket connect .. whcih causes "network on UI" thread issues on recent Android.

Comment: I see, thanks for the details. Does it support Tornado Websockets 2.2? Because, just today I figured that weberkneckt supports a max of 2.1.

Comment: Autobahn for Android supports WebSockets protocol draft version Hybi-10 up to teh final RFC6455. I don't known what Tornado WS 2.2 implements ..

Comment: I tried the AutoBahn "Broadcast Client" library. See "Update" above. But I fail to connect to the server. Could you help me out?

Comment: I've added more debug log output -- could you fetch the latest

https://github.com/oberstet/AutobahnAndroid

rebuild, rerun, and reattach the adb logcat output?

Hopefully that will shed some light upon the issue.

Comment: Actually, I just misunderstood the problem. Turns out, actually the connection is established with the server ( I am Logging "ActiclesListActivity: Connected to ws://192.168.0.137:8888/ in the onOpen method" and then for some reason, the connection is lost.

Comment: It seems the server is dropping the TCP connection after replying to handshake .. I see if I can get Tornado 2.2 (that's what you are using, right?) running .. and that includes already a WS server implementation? Also, could you pastebin your server code (something stripped down is sufficient), so I can test?

Comment: It's a test webserver and all the server code is as above under "Tornado Server". I am on 2.1.1. Should I upgrade?

Comment: Works for me: Tornado 2.2 + your code above + Echo client demo from Autobahn Android. Probably Tornado 2.1 WS impl. might be too old .. try 2.2 ..

Comment: Gotcha. I just upgraded to 2.2 and it worked! Awesome! Thanks!! I have decided to use your library as it's much more active and supports the final RFC 6455 protocol. Thansk for all the support!

Comment: excellent;) should you run into issues again, don't hesitate to contact again .. probably best on the mailing list http://groups.google.com/group/autobahnws which I monitor more closely ..

Comment: Sure, thanks! That helps. I am now testing this client with a simple SocketIO webserver. Is this supported? You can respond in your forum.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination ... I faced similar issue and yes the client I use supports Hypi only HybiParser.java